# How to compare several dates in one column with several loops?

Tags: vba, excel

I am so desperate that I hope you can help me.

I have this problem : For each name I have in the "Resources" sheet, I need to see a "Start Date". The "Start Date" comes from the "Demand" sheet. It's the closest date to today's date from the column G.

Meaning : For Mr. X, I have 10 different dates. Today's 01/03/2017. So all the dates before this one are out of scope. It remains 5 dates (from March to December 2017). I want to see the closest date to today meaning 31/03/2017.

But, for each name, I don't obviously have the same amount of dates (from 1 to 10 dates per name, more or less). That's why I created loops so I can go through my whole list of dates.

My problem is that if I try to set up a variable for this specific date I want to see, my loops will just erase the value previously saved. I don't know how to do... To begin with my cell is blank so even if I put today's date to compare and code out of the loop it still won't work...

Sample : http://www.cjoint.com/c/GCbpoFz64P2

```
Sub ICStart()

    Sheets("Resources").Select
    Nb_tot1 = 5
    While Cells(Nb_tot1, 1).Value <> ""
        Nb_tot1 = Nb_tot1 + 1
    Wend
    Nb_tot1 = Nb_tot1 - 5
    MsgBox "Total Lines is : " & Nb_tot1 & "."

    Sheets("Demande").Select

    Nb_tot2 = 3
    While Cells(Nb_tot2, 14).Value <> ""
        Nb_tot2 = Nb_tot2 + 1
    Wend
    Nb_tot2 = Nb_tot2 - 3
    MsgBox "Total Lines is : " & Nb_tot2 & "."

    For i = 5 To Nb_tot1 + 5 - 1
        Sheets("Resources").Select
        Name = Cells(i, 1)
        Sheets("Demande").Select
        End_date_temp = Worksheets("Demande").Cells(3, 7)
        For j = 3 To Nb_tot2
            Sheets("Demande").Select
            Worksheets("Resources").Cells(i, 8) = End_date_temp
            Commit = Cells(j, 12)
            An = Year(Cells(j, 7))
            End_date = Cells(j, 7)
            If Cells(j, 14) = Name And Commit = "Y" And An <> "2100" And An >= Year(Now) And End_date >= Date Then
                End_date_temp = End_date
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

The main issue is that I can't find how to write that line :

```
End_date_temp = Worksheets("Demande - Projets").Cells(3, 7)
```

Comment: You need to provide some sample data.

Comment: http://www.cjoint.com/c/GCbpoFz64P2

Comment: I hope it will be enough. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Update your question with sample data.

Comment: Dates are finicky.  When comparing or looking for dates you have to make sure they are the exact same type of variable.  for instance, DateValue(stringVariable) is telling Excel to create a date variable from what ever is in the stringVariable.  If stringVariable = "03/31/2017" then you have no problems.  But if stringVariable = "Mrs. Beasley" then it will return a blank.  Which I suspect is the reason your previous cell is being "ERASED".  It's not being erased though, it's being replaced with a blank.  Go here to learn about date variables. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you started.

```
Sub test()
    Dim person As String

    person = Worksheets("Resources").Range("A2")
    Debug.Print GetClosestDate(person)
End Sub

Function GetClosestDate(person As String)
    Dim cl As Range, today As Date, closestDate As Date

    today = VBA.Now

    For Each cl In Worksheets("Demand").Range("G1:G8")
        If cl.Offset(0, 7) = person Then           // this picks up name column N

            If cl >= today Then
                If closestDate = "00:00:00" Then   //Default value for uninitialised date object
                    closestDate = cl.Value
                Else
                    If CInt(cl - today) < CInt(closestDate - today) Then
                        closestDate = cl.Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cl

    GetClosestDate = closestDate

End Function
```

- I use a function `GetClosestDate` to find the closest date for a person
- It assumes any date earlier than today can be ignored
- It loops over dates and compares whether it is closer to today than the stored date

You will need to modify the code to handle looping over names in `Resources` etc. but I think - at least in principle - this code is what you need.

Comment: Hello Alex P, I just saw your reply. Thank you very much, it's exactly what I need !

Comment: Great! As I said in my answer, you will need to tweak the code to fit your specific set-up.

Comment: Alex P thanks again for your help. I managed to tweak the code so it fits my needs. But now, I realised that I also need to use the dates earlier to today. Meaning, if I only have dates in 2016, I want the closest to today. So it's basically the same thing but with dates earlier than today. I'm stuck though... Could you help me with this too please..?

Comment: I think you can just remove the **if cl > today...** statement